# JQuery validation plugin onclick link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that uses a link to submit the results.
I'm using Jquery validation plugin.

I can get the form to validate if I use a normal button to submit the form.
How can I call the Jquery function from a hyperlink instead of a button.
Here's my jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#newsletter_form').validate({ 
            rules: {
                CONTACTS_EMAIL: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                CONTACTS_PRIVACY_POLICY_AGREE: "required",
            },
            messages: {
                CONTACTS_PRIVACY_POLICY_AGREE: "<?php echo $FRM_ERRMSG_CONTACTS_PRIVACY_POLICY_AGREE;?>",
                CONTACTS_EMAIL: {
                  required: "<?php echo $FRM_ERRMSG_CONTACTS_EMAIL;?>",
                  email: "<?php echo $FRM_ERRMSG_CONTACTS_EMAIL_FORMAT;?>"
                }
              },
            submitHandler: function (form) { 
                form.submit();
            }
        });   
    });
 </script>
```

And here is my html (with some php inside to be ignored)

```
<form id="newsletter_form" name="newsletter_form" action="newsletter_submit.php" method="post" >
        <br>
        <div class="mc-field-group">
            <input type="text" name="CONTACTS_EMAIL" placeholder="*<?echo $EMAIL_FIELD_TEXT;?>" style="width: 280px;font-size: 20px;" /><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CONTACTS_PRIVACY_POLICY_AGREE"> <?echo $PRIVACY_POLICY;?> * <label for="CONTACTS_PRIVACY_POLICY_AGREE" class="error" style="display:none;"></label>

            <input type="hidden" name="CONTACTS_LANGUAGE" value="<?echo $language;?>">
            <div>
                <input type='submit' style='position:absolute;top:0;left:-9999px;width:1px;height:1px' name='newsletter_form'>
                <a style="margin-top:22px;" class="wsite-button external-link" onclick="document.getElementById('newsletter_form').submit()"> 
                <span class="wsite-button-inner"><?echo $BUTTON_TEXT;?></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: remove from your code  
`<input type='submit' ....>` tag. And then your tag <a></a> will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using jQuery to trigger the submit event:

```
onclick="$('#commentForm').submit();"
```

There's a lot that could be improved here, but that may fix your core problem. I remember something like this happening to me a long time ago.